# Finding the column index for the 1 in each row of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have the following matrix in Matlab:

```
M = [0 0 1
     1 0 0
     0 1 0
     1 0 0
     0 0 1];
```

Each row has exactly one 1. How can I  (without looping) determine a column vector so that the first element is a 2 if there is a 1 in the second column, the second element is a 3 for a one in the third column etc.? The above example should turn into:

```
M = [ 3
      1
      2
      1
      3];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually solve this with simple matrix multiplication.

```
result = M * (1:size(M, 2)).';

     3
     1
     2
     1
     3
```

This works by multiplying your M x 3 matrix with a 3 x 1 array where the elements of the 3x1 are simply `[1; 2; 3]`. Briefly, for each row of `M`, element-wise multiplication is performed with the 3 x 1 array. Only the 1's in the row of `M` will yield anything in the result. Then the result of this element-wise multiplication is summed. Because you only have one "1" per row, the result is going to be the column index where that 1 is located.

So for example for the first row of `M`.

```
element_wise_multiplication = [0 0 1] .* [1 2 3]

    [0, 0, 3]

sum(element_wise_multiplication)

    3
```

**Update**

Based on the solutions provided by [@reyryeng](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35953070/670206) and [@Luis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35966907/670206) below, I decided to run a comparison to see how the performance of the various methods compared.

To setup the test matrix (`M`) I created a matrix of the form specified in the original question and varied the number of rows. Which column had the 1 was chosen randomly using `randi([1 nCols], size(M, 1))`. Execution times were analyzed using `timeit`.

When run using `M` of type `double` (MATLAB's default) you get the following execution times.

[image]

If `M` is a `logical`, then the matrix multiplication takes a hit due to the fact that it has to be converted to a numerical type prior to matrix multiplication, whereas the other two have a bit of a performance improvement.

[image]

Here is the test code that I used.

```
sizes = round(linspace(100, 100000, 100));
times = zeros(numel(sizes), 3);

for k = 1:numel(sizes)
    M = generateM(sizes(k));
    times(k,1) = timeit(@()M * (1:size(M, 2)).');
    M = generateM(sizes(k));
    times(k,2) = timeit(@()max(M, [], 2), 2);
    M = generateM(sizes(k));
    times(k,3) = timeit(@()find(M.'), 2);
end

figure
plot(range, times / 1000);
legend({'Multiplication', 'Max', 'Find'})
xlabel('Number of rows in M')
ylabel('Execution Time (ms)')

function M = generateM(nRows)
    M = zeros(nRows, 3);
    col = randi([1 size(M, 2)], 1, size(M, 1));
    M(sub2ind(size(M), 1:numel(col), col)) = 1;
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your very fast answer. It is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

You can also abuse [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) and observe the **row** positions of the transpose of `M`.  You have to transpose the matrix first as `find` operates in column major order:

```
M = [0 0 1
     1 0 0
     0 1 0
     1 0 0
     0 0 1];

[out,~] = find(M.');
```

Not sure if this is faster than matrix multiplication though.

Comment: `find` is one of the rare occasions where `[out,~] = ...` is not the same as `out = ...`

Comment: @LuisMendo aha yes sir!

Answer (score 2):

Yet another approach: use the second output of [`max`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html):

```
[~, result] = max(M.', [], 1);
```

Or, as suggested by [@rayryeng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3250829/rayryeng), use `max` along the second dimension instead of transposing `M`:

```
[~, result] = max(M, [], 2);
```

For

```
M = [0 0 1
     1 0 0
     0 1 0
     1 0 0
     0 0 1];
```

this gives

```
result =
     3     1     2     1     3
```

If `M` contains more than one `1` in a given row, this will give the index of the first such `1`.

Comment: Nicely done. I always forget about using `max` this way. I wonder what the performance comparison is between all approaches. My money is on `max`

Comment: Is there a performance difference if you didn't transpose the matrix and specified looking along the rows of the matrix instead? Like specifying the dimension to look at to be `2`?