# Identify the points of different sector of circle using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, coordinates, geometry

I have a circle and partition this circle into 3 sector(120 angle each).In circle area,there are some known points(Coordinates of point are known).I want to know which point belongs to which sector.As a output i want to obtain the point of individual sector.

I draw the circle, divide into sector and plot some points. But I couldn't identify which point belongs to which sector.
How can I get this? If anyone have any source code for this process using MATLAB, it helps me much.

Here, I include my source code

```
x0 = 2;     % origin x-coordinate
y0 = 1;     % origin y-coordinate
r  = 1;     % radius of circle
n  = 3;     % number of pieces

% predefined points -> [x1,x2,xn;y1,y2,yn]

p = [ 1.5, 2.0, 1.50, 2.4, 1.8, 1.5, 1.7, 2.0, 1.8, 2.5, 2.7, 2.0, 1.3, 1.2, 1.4, 2.2, 1.7, 1.2;
  0.2, 0.8, 1.20, 1.0, 1.3, 0.8, 1.1, 1.4, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 1.1, 1.3, 1.5, 1.8, 1.5, 1.1];

% calculate circle

theta = -pi:0.01:pi;

cirx = r*cos(theta) + x0;  

ciry = r*sin(theta) + y0;

% initial plot

figure; 
hold on;

axis square;

plot(x0,y0,'or');           % origin

plot(cirx,ciry);            % circle

plot(p(1,:),p(2,:),'go');   % predefined points

% calculate and plot separations

ciro = linspace(-pi,pi,n+1);

for k = 1:(numel(ciro))

ph(k) = plot([x0,x0+r*cos(ciro(k))],[y0,y0+r*sin(ciro(k))]); 

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach that you should take, is to convert each cartesian (x,y) point into it's polar equivalent (rho, theta) using the origin (`x0`, `y0`) as the center. You can then use the `theta` value to determine what sector it belongs to.

```
% Compute polar coordinates 
[theta, rho] = cart2pol(p(1,:) - x0, p(2,:) - y0);

% Sector theta values with an extra one at the end for periodicity
sector_thetas = linspace(-pi,pi,n+1);

% Identify which sector it falls into by checking theta against one 
% sector and then the next. Should be greater than one and less than the other
membership = bsxfun(@le, sector_thetas(1:end-1).', theta) & ...
             bsxfun(@gt, sector_thetas(2:end).', theta);

% The result is [nRows x nPoints] and each column will contain a 1 in the row
% corresponding to the sector it belongs to.

% Get the index of which sector it belongs to
% This uses the trick here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35950922/finding-the-column-index-for-the-1-in-each-row-of-a-matrix/35951036#35951036
sector = (1:n) * membership;
```

Then if we plot the different sectors, we can ensure that things were grouped appropriately

```
colors = 'grb';

for k = 1:n
    toplot = sector == k;
    p(k) = plot(p(1, toplot), p(2, toplot), ...
                'Color', colors(k), ...
                'Marker', 'o', ...
                'DisplayName', sprintf('Sector %d', k));
end

legend(p);
```

[image]

If you want to know the point indices that belong within each group, you could do the following.

```
members = arrayfun(@(x)find(sector == x), 1:n, 'uniform', 0);
celldisp(members)

    members{1} =

        1     2     6     9    12

    members{2} =

        4    10    11

    members{3} =

        3     5     7     8    13    14    15    16    17    18
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...its exactly same that i want.

Comment: @ Suever, I have a question. If i want to number the point.Suppose 1,2,...18 and want to get as a output scetor 1={point 1,2,6,9,12} and sector 2={point 4,10,11} and sector 3={point 3,5,...}. Which portion of code i need to change?Actually i want to show output that way.

Comment: @Tina I have updated my post with an example of how to do this at the bottom

Comment: Quite elegant solution, @Suever!